# Function not evaluating as expected

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I'm not sure I understand why this is not working and why it's giving different answers:

A simple example illustrating the issue is below:

```
U[x_, p_] := RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ 
   (v - p - x >= 0 && 0 <= v <= 1 ) , {v}]]

q[p_] := (x /. FindRoot[x - U[x, p] == 0, {x, 0.5, 0, 1}])

q[.4]

(q[p]) /. {p -> 0.4}
```

Why are those two evaluations not consistent? I would think that the last line would do the same thing as the line before it, but it gives a different answer.

Comment: Change the definition  of `q` to `q[p_?NumericQ] := (x /. FindRoot[x - U[x, p] == 0, {x, 0.5, 0, 1}])` Since the function uses a numeric technique, it needs to be restricted to a numeric argument.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I also want to ask why this doesn't work:

 Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{
   (v - p - x >  0 ) /. {x -> q[p]}
   }, {v, 0.000000001, 1}, {c, 0.001, 1} (* 
  Just to see it as a 2D RegionPlot *), 
  FrameLabel -> Automatic], {p, .001, 1}]

Even after following the suggestion above, there is still an 'Uncaught SystemException' error

Comment: I suggest that you formulate a new question. In your `RegionPlot` what does `c` represent? It must relate to the `Region` to be plotted.

Comment: I just used c to make it into a 2d regionplot. There is no c in the model, so I'm expecting a vertical band of blue across all c for the range of v for which the inequality holds. I'll make another post. Thanks again!

Comment: Keep in mind that the function `q` will also fail if `x` has a value. It's better to use `Module[{x}, x /. FindRoot[x - U[x, p] == 0, {x, 0.5, 0, 1}]]` to make sure that's not going to be an issue.